# __NSCFNumber return negative value

Tags: ios, nsnumber

For some reason i cant set my NSNumber value.

Code is simple:

```
    obj.objectId = [filteredArr[i] valueForKey:@"idx"];
```

Where `[[filteredArr[i] valueForKey:@"idx"] class]` is `__NSCFNumber`.

It should be a number from 0 to 200.. but it is actually -5764607523034234861

Comment: `[[filteredArr[i] valueForKey:@"idx"] integerValue]`? `objectId` is supposed to be a NSNumber, NSInteger, etc. ?

Comment: NSLog(@"mutArNam %ld", (long)[((CIdNamedObject*)mutArr[0]).objectId integerValue]);
 still shows -5764607523034234861

Comment: If you log `NSLog(@"Value: %@", [filteredArr[i] valueForKey:@"idx"])`, you have the wrong one?

Comment: issue is in creating your dict  ** 5764607523034234861** Garbage value happens when type mis-match like putting long range value at place of int range

Comment: @MikeAlter okay, that help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSNumber and NSString respond to the methods -intValue which returns an int.

```
NSNumber *myNumber = @([[filteredArr[i] valueForKey:@"idx"]intValue]);
```

This may help you.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban can you please post the log NSLog(@"Value: %@", [filteredArr[i] valueForKey:@"idx"])

Comment: Value: -5764607523034233021